# List of multiple objects c++

Tags: c++, list, class, object

I got some issues with the use of `std::list`. I can use it well with list of a "simple" type of data, or list of one type of object.

I want to create a list of three different types of objects. For example, there are three types of objects: class p1, class p2, class p3.
And I want to create a list which contains objects of these three.

```
class p1 {
...
};

class p2 {
...
};

class p3 {
...
};

int main() {
    std::list<whatshouldiInserthere?> namelist;
}
```

I have already tried with template, but no way. Could you post an example source code?

Comment: You are mixing up *objects* with *classes*.

Comment: I would first question *why* you want to do this? There may be a better way.

Comment: How do you expect to use `namelist`? There's no point creating a data structure unless you plan to use it for something, and if you tell us how you will use it, then we can help you. Tell us how you will put data into `namelist` and, more importantly, how you will read the data in `namelist`.

Answer (score 10):

- You can use a list of `void *`, giving up on an elegant and modern solution
- You could instead derive all your objects from a base class, then make your list contain pointers to that base class instead
- You could use `boost::variant` or `boost::any` as a sort of a type safe `void *`. This is actually a lot better than it sounds because thanks to template magic it doesn't have extra indirection levels, and still doesn't require the same base class

Comment: The second pointer is a perfect approach incase your system demands an object oriented approach.

Comment: The problem with this answer is it is handing a young child the choice between a handgun, a rocket and a chainsaw when the child asks "how do I deal with the monster under the bed?"  What the child really needs is a glass of water.  (oh, and you forgot the gernade option: type erasure)

Comment: @Yakk, that's the first case, call it `void *` and you're done. Anyway I think you're a bit off, it's very common to derive your types from the same base class in most OOP languages and use that base type in your collections.

Comment: @Blindy `void*` isn't what I'd call type erasing.  Type erasing is something like `std::function`, where you erase everything about a type except what you care about (and those common properties are then exposed, without being intrusive and injecting interfaces into the type).  Even in that case, storing raw pointers to an interface in a `std::list` is still very rarely a good idea.  And when someone who doesn't know the difference between a class and an object asks the question, it isn't usually the thing they should be doing.

Answer (score 2):

`whatshouldiInserthere` does not exist. You need to store variants (like `boost::variant`, `boost::any`, etc.), which hold instances of your classes.

Comment: ....or have those three classes inherit from a single base class and store pointers to that.